# Office 365 / SharepPoint Online Team site Usage

Tags: office-365, auditing, site-usage

I have been creating SharePoint Site usage ( Team and Group) and SharePoint User access report via the Admin Centre -> Reports-> Usage menu.  The former is limited to Site Collection access, so will be great with Office 365 Group / Microsoft Teams sites when we roll these out.  However, with  old school: team (sub) sites the report isn't very granular.

As anybody been able to get any sub site stats via any free tools or PowerShell?If not I am guessing I am looking at commercial products like AvePoint.

Comment: I've used PowerShell to dump all the site collection sizes into a csv, then I read that CSV in Power BI. It doesn't dive into the subsite level, but if we see a site trending up, we'll start looking at storman.aspx to see who the culprits are and start conversations on storage and retention.

Comment: One thing I am thinking of doing is to get the user access reports as CSV and then import and argument a custom PSObject with location or team of each user. I could "group by" to get a handle on agregate usage per team site ( and OneDrives) .. This would be a rough guide of course

Comment: I think in that case  `get-sposite -limit all -includepersonalsite | Select Url, StorageUsageCurrent, StorageQuota, Owner, Template | Export-CSV` would get you all the data you need

Comment: Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Get-SPOSite -limit all -includepersonalsite $false | Select Url, StorageUsageCurrent, StorageQuota, Owner, Template really reports on site collections  .  Note, I have an old version of pnp commandlets to remove.